# How to duplicate Binding of Isaac: Repentance saves?

Tags: achievements, the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-repentance

I recently got Dead God in The Binding of Isaac, and I saw that you can get a unique image on the file select when you get dead god on all 3 saves. I REALLY don't want to get all achievements again twice, does anyone know how to duplicate a save file so I can get the Infinity% screen?